# Creating a method to return a value from a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, methods

I've been scratching my head here, I'm getting confused as to the structure of the `Main` class and where exactly are my methods supposed to belong (and where to call them). I'm trying to create a simple method that takes a string, and within that method returns the value of that string from a dictionary defined within the method. This is what I have:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {

    static int PizzaTotal (string pizzaType)
    {
      Dictionary<string, int> PizzaCost = new Dictionary<string, int>()
      {
          { "Cheese", 10 },
          { "Pepperoni", 11 },
          { "Vegetarian", 12 },
      };
      return PizzaCost[pizzaType];
    }
  }
  return PizzaTotal["Cheese"];
}
```

I'm getting a bunch of `Unexpected symbol` errors, which I'm assuming is indicating that the method is written in the wrong place. Any suggestions?

Comment: You cant have a return statement outside your Main method

Comment: Remove the line return PizzaTotal["Cheese"];

Answer (score 2):

Change your return statement like this. This will run the program and exit but if you are calling it from another process, you'll get the number associated with the type.

Also, you cannot call a method with [ ]. You use ( ). Change the line where you are calling the method as well. `Console.WriteLine(PizzaTotal("Cheese"));`

```
class MainClass 
{
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
       return PizzaTotal("Cheese"); // Place it here. before the curly braces
       // OR Print It.
       Console.WriteLine(PizzaTotal("Cheese"));
       Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int PizzaTotal(string pizzaType)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> PizzaCost = new Dictionary<string, int>()
            {
                { "Cheese", 10 },
                { "Pepperoni", 11 },
                { "Vegetarian", 12 },
            };
        return PizzaCost[pizzaType];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you, that makes a lot more sense. I removed the `return` from the call in the `Main` method but it's still not returning the integer value. Am I missing something else?

Comment: @user7496931 Square brackets. Use ( ) instead of [ ] for passing arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your Pizzatotal declaration is inside the Main method. This makes it a local function, not a method. Local functions are a recent addition to C#, so you may be using an older version of the language. Most likely what you want is a method, which you can achieve by moving the declaration out of the main method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a sample to use dictionary:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass {
    static private protected Dictionary<string, int> pizzaCost = new Dictionary<string, int>() 
    {
          { "Sample-A", 1 },
          { "Sample-B", 2 },
          { "Sample-C", 3 }
    };

    static void Main (string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Pizza Total: {0}", pizzaCost["Sample-A"] + pizzaCost["Sample-B"] + pizzaCost["Sample-C"]);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```